# how to maintain typesafe even after compile from ts to js

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-safety

**TS code :**

```
function f(val1:number) {
    console.log(val1);
}
```

**JS code, after compile :**

```
function f(val1) {
    console.log(val1);
}
```

Is there any way to maintain type safe even after converting to js from ts?

Comment: TS already maintains the typesafety for you. If you have any calls to `f` using, for example, a string then the compilation would fail.

Comment: If type safety was a feature of JavaScript, then why else would TypeScript have been created?

Comment: decorators … as in nestjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to keep types after compilation to JS. JS has no concept of static types. Typescript is a static type checker, the output is plain JS. Therefore no types can persist after compilation.

If you write your application in TS, the compiler will validate that what you are doing is type safe so at runtime things should work. (Although even in TS code you can break type safety and do unsafe things with `any` and type assertions)

Comment: I guess technically you could kind of, sort of hack in  something that could be called type safety if you really squint your eyes a lot. Just make all your function do something like `if (!(typeof param == "number")) throw Error("Type safety!");` - it's not really type safety but it's the only thing in vanilla JavaScript even approaching it. It's also terrible but there you go.

Comment: @vlaz depends on your definition of type safety I guess :) That can work, but it's a runtime check. When I think of type safety I think of static type checking .... but that could be what the OP is looking for.

Comment: `definition of type safety I guess` that's why I mentioned squinting. You probably also need to down several shots of <hard alcohol of your choice> to start really calling it that. But yes, I agree - it isn't type safety because there isn't real type safety in JS. It's just the only thing that provides any sort of type checking in an application.

Comment: @Thilo I agree with that as well. Again, the only type checking you can do is the one that throws you runtime errors. Mostly because there is no "build time" for JS unless you count, say, minification process as one. But in reality, that's converting your code into the same code but being written differently, not converting your code to a *different* thing (e.g, bytecode). You could use notation in comments and let a tool parse it to tell you if you have wrong calls (e.g., JSDoc + tern.js) but that's again not "building" but static analysis that you can run prior to running the code.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a dynamically type language. It will convert the types according to need - see [type coercion](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839).

If you really want to make sure that some type is used in your function you have to check it in your code.
For example:

```
function f(val1) {
    if (typeof val1 !== "number") {
        throw new Error("not a number");
    }
    console.log(val1);
}
```

Keep in mind that this is just an example.
If you try passing a `var x = new Number(42)` to the function it will still throw the error as the `typeof x` is `object`.
So you need to take extra care when doing these kinds of checks.